# Need functional information about hide video from vimeo.com privacy

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I have seen for pro/plus members there is an option "Hide this video from Vimeo.com (Plus + PRO only)".
I want to ask that if i am using this option then for comment/like on video vimeo login is displayed or not?

Answer (score 1):

Hide from Vimeo simply means you can not access the video directly on vimeo.com. Once the video is embedded on your site, everything else should behave normally.

Comment: Hello Dashron, Thanks for reply, I understood your answer and i have another doubt is that when we are calling API for video which is hide from vimeo than in webpage where video in embed comment and like functionality will work or not?